# No new mail notification at apple mail dock icon when rules apply

Tags: email, notifications, mail-rules

I've set a rule in apple mail. It's very simple. If a specific individual sends me mail it moves it directly to the destination folder. The problem is that it does not notify me that a mail arrived! If I open mail program I see that I have one new massage in the directory, but the apple mail icon at the dock have no notifications at all.

Is it possible to configure Mail.app so it shows unread count in specific other mailboxes, in addition to the inbox?

Answer (score 2):

Mail does only look at one or all mailboxes for the count, it is set in Mail->Preferences->General, the field "Doc unread count"

You can make it look at a more complex setup by using Smart mailboxes.

In this case I would create a new Smart mailbox say Counter which would contain rules for any of Mailbox is Inbox and the destination folder.

Answer (score 1):

You could change the Dock unread count to count all mailboxes instead of just the inbox.

Go to Mail Preferences / General / Dock Unread Count.
Change from "Inbox Only" to "All Mailboxes"

You could also modify the rule that moves the mail. 
Edit your rule that moves the mail. Click the + icon to add another action. You could then add an action to send a notification, bounce the dock icon or run an Applescript to alert you to new mail.